# TypeError: PNI() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, function, class, tkinter

Any help with this problem would be much appreciated.
I keep getting the below error and can not figure out why.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Beast\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: PNI() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Below is the code that I have so far.
From what I can tell the problem is caused by the def PNI function.
I have tried that function is a simplified program and it worked so any help making it work here will be much appreciated.

```
from tkinter import *
import pandas as pd
import os
import shutil
import time

#Font sizes
LARGE_FONT = ("Verdana", 12)

#Main frame
class IntegrationAPP(Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    
        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = Frame(self)
        
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        
        self.frames = {}
        
        for F in (StartPage, Test):
            
            frame = F(container, self)
            
            self.frames[F] = frame
            
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        
        self.show_frame(StartPage)
        
    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        #Create entry feild
        pni = Entry(self, width=50)
        pni.insert(0, 'Enter project number')

        #Pull data from entry feild
        def PNI(self, *args, **kwargs):
            label1 = Label(self, text = pni.get())
            label1.grid(row=0, column=2)

        #Create submit button
        buttonpni = Button(self, text="Submit", command=PNI)

        #Location in grid
        pni.grid(row=0, column=0)
        buttonpni.grid(row=1, column=0)

#Future epansion
class Test(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label1 = Label(self, text="Hello", font=LARGE_FONT)
        
        label1.grid(row=0, column=0)

app = IntegrationAPP()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: The `PNI()` has incorrect indentation.

Answer (score 0):

Move this to the left, currently it's inside **init** function. Just an indentation problem basically. Usually most IDEs offer you to move selected code left and right with ctrl+{ or ctrl+}

```
 #Pull data from entry feild
    def PNI(self, *args, **kwargs):
        label1 = Label(self, text = pni.get())
        label1.grid(row=0, column=2)
```